# Moving tabs in Chrome is clunky / awkwardly slow

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

In `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`, fresh install + `Chrome` from Google's page, I'm having the following issue:  when having more than one tab open in `Chrome 36.0.1985.125`, the animation when moving the tab's position is really clunky.  However, when creating or removing a tab the animation looks fine and responsive, as you should expect.

Let's suppose you have `tab a` and `tab b` open, `tab a` to the left, and `tab b` to the right - you put your pointer above `tab a` and press the left click.  While pressed, you move the pointer to the right, so the tabs switch places with each other.  Then is when the animation turns slow.

**Is this a known issue?  If so, how can I fix it?**

System:

```
Processor: AMD A6-3420M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4
Memory:    8GB
Graphics:  Gallium 0.4 on AMD SUMO
OS type:   64-bit
```

---

```
chrome://gpu/

Graphics Feature 

Status Canvas: Hardware accelerated 
Flash 3D: Hardware accelerated 
Flash Stage3D: Hardware accelerated 
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Hardware accelerated 
Compositing: Hardware accelerated and threaded. 
Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled. 
Video Decode: Hardware accelerated 
Video Encode: Hardware accelerated 
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
```

Answer (score 2):

Visit `chrome://gpu/` in `Chrome` and see if **hardware acceleration** is enabled.

If it is enabled, try reinstalling `Chrome` or use `Chromium Browser`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

To use hardware acceleration in `Chrome`, open a new tab, go to `chrome://flags`, search for `Override software rendering list`, enable it and restart `Chrome`.

Comment: Thanks for your response - after setting the `Override software rendering list` flag to *enabled*, the behavior still continues.  I tried with chromium, but the slowness is in there as well.  +1 for the `chrome://gpu/` and `chrome://flags` tip.

Comment: Please post the output of `$ glxinfo | grep render`. Also, run `$ top` and then replicate the issue. Does the CPU usage spike substantially?

Comment: Also, try disabling `GPU Composting` in `chrome://flags`.